# UILabel: change a text color when click button

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am beginner in iOS programming.

So, I want to change the text color when user click button.

My code:

```
- (IBAction)buttonGetText:(id)sender {
self.textChange.textColor = "red"; 
}
```

But it doesn't work. What do I need to do? 
Thank you everyone.

Comment: just make self.textChange.textColor = [UIColor redColor];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
self.textChange.textColor = "red";
```

Doesn't make sense, you need to use `UIColor`.

Try this:

```
self.textChange.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Comment: I tried to use it, but it doesn't work. The text didn't change. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The answer is correct, should be working. Check if your textChange is a valid UILabel.

Comment: LOL, red color wasn't changed. It didn't work, but I did blue color and it works. :) Thank you.

Comment: So, I could do it. Thank you everyone who answered on my question.

Comment: Accept an answer by checking the tick